# Show alert box every X seconds, but wait Y seconds first

Tags: javascript

I try to show an alert box every X seconds, but it should first wait Y seconds before starting.

I tried it like this, but this will only show the alert box once.

```js
var X = 2000;
var Y = 5000;

setTimeout(function(){
        var IntervalID = setInterval(show_alert("hello"), X);
    }, 
Y);

function show_alert(str)
{
  alert(str);
}
```

Can someone explain why it does not work as expected?

Comment: `setInterval` expects parameter to be a `function`, whereas you pass **returning value** of your function call which is `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `show_alert("hello")` calls a function as you've told once because you're *directly calling it*. Instead you need to provide a function which passes the `behavior`, so, in your case which is calling your function. See:

```js
var X = 2000;
var Y = 5000;

setTimeout
(
  function()
  {
    var IntervalID = setInterval(function() { show_alert("hello") }, X);
  },
  Y
);

function show_alert(str)
{
  alert(str);
}
```

Additionally, it calls your function only after X + Y. If you want to run it after X only you need to call it once when you run interval, see:

```js
var X = 2000;
var Y = 5000;

setTimeout
(
  function()
  {
    var IntervalID = setInterval(function() { show_alert("hello") }, X);

    show_alert("hello");
  },
  Y
);

function show_alert(str)
{
  alert(str);
}
```

Comment: The second example does also run the script after X+Y seconds?

Comment: @EdwardBlack, nope, it registers an interval with a behavior function (asynchronously, so the JS goes forward directly) and then calls the function directly.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are calling the function with the first alert, making it pass `undefined` as the handler function every consecutive time. `bind` the param to the function instead.

```
var X = 2000;
var Y = 5000;

setTimeout
(
  function()
  {
    var IntervalID = setInterval(show_alert.bind(null, 'hello'), X);
  },
  Y
);

function show_alert(str)
{
  alert(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call function using bind.

```
setInterval(show_alert.bind(null, 'hello'), X);
```